# Entity Framework code first using models defined with non-native types

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a question regarding EF Code First with MVC. Currently I know how to create controllers and views out a model that has all the atributtes as native types such as (int, string, etc.).

What if I have a model that one its attributes is a type defined in another model in my project?

Something like

```
public class Partido
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public Seleccion Local { get; set; }
        public Seleccion Visitante { get; set; }
        public Resultado Marcador { get; set; }
    }
```

Where `Seleccion` and `Resultado` are defined each one in the same model namespace of the project.

Comment: Right click on Controller folder, tell I want a new controller out of Partido model and one context. Then I repeat the same but with the View folder.

Comment: And what was the result?

Comment: I see nothing. The generated HTML is empty. I asume that is because it does not recognize Seleccion and Resultado plus ID is the PK for the table in the DB.

Answer (score 1):

Decorate `Seleccion` and `Resultado` classes with `ComplexType` attribute. Example:

```
public class Partido
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public Seleccion Local { get; set; }
    public Seleccion Visitante { get; set; }
    public Resultado Marcador { get; set; }
}

[ComplexType]
public class Seleccion {} 

[ComplexType]
public class Resultado {}
```

Entity Framework will generate appropriate colums in 'Partido' table that will correspond to `Seleccion` and `Resultado` class properties.

You can learn more about it here: [Code First Data Annotations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg193958.aspx)

Comment: It didn't work I think becasue reading the link you provided the ComplexType they cannot be tracked in the database using and ID which I do in the Seleccion and Resultado definition.

Comment: Yes, these classes must act as value objects and cannot have key properties.

Comment: So, basically it is imposible to generate automatically a controller/view out of model that is compound by another model that does have a key? So, I guess it is becasue you shouldn't do that. My question now is, what should you do in that case? Which pattern do I ought to follow? Thanks!!

Comment: You could also try to decorate `Selection` and `Resultado` id properties with `[NotMapped]`. I'm not sure if it's going to work, because I've never tried it. Btw why can't you treat these classes as entities and put them in your `DbContext` class? EF will create tables for them and in `Partido` entity they will be treated as foreign keys.

Comment: The idea is that ''Seleccion'' and ''Resultado'' they are entities as well. I mean, the same way ''Partido'' is. I am not sure if I understood you correctly in that last point...